# Kotlin flow not getting an updated value

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

I created a simple Flow to allow to reset any flow's value. But when I started using it with different other operators I see some weird stuff going on. Here is my code (also the [playground link](https://pl.kotl.in/gyaPEcc83)):

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.*

class ResettableFlow<T>(source: Flow<T>, private val defaultValue: T): Flow<T> {
    private val resetTrigger = MutableSharedFlow<T>()

    private val mergedFlow = merge(source, resetTrigger).onEach { println("ResettableFlow: onEach $it") }

    override suspend fun collect(collector: FlowCollector<T>) {
        mergedFlow.collect(collector)
    }

    fun reset() {
        resetTrigger.tryEmit(defaultValue)
    }
}

fun <T> Flow<T>.toResettable(defaultValue: T) = ResettableFlow(this, defaultValue)


fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        val state1 = MutableStateFlow(1)
        val resettable1 = state1.toResettable(0)

        val state2 = MutableStateFlow("a")
        val resettable2 = state2.toResettable("...")

        val combined = resettable1.combine(resettable2) { i, s -> "$i $s" }
            .onEach { println(it) }
            .stateIn(this, SharingStarted.WhileSubscribed(5000), "init")

        val job = combined.launchIn(this)

        state1.value = 10
        state2.value = "d"

        delay(1000)

        resettable1.reset()
        resettable2.reset()

        delay(1000)

        // this never exits
        combined.first { it == "0 ..."}

        // this also never ends
        //while (combined.value != "0 ...") {
        //    delay(1000)
        //}

        println("found!")

        delay(1000)
        job.cancel()

        this.cancel()
    }   
}
```

So I would expect that after calling `reset()` on both sources I would eventually get the reset values in the `combined` flow. However, this never happens, "found!" is never printed.

I have similar code in my ViewModel using viewModelScope as my scope, and there I'm having similar issues, but occasionally I see the values, so might be a race condition.

What is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the `merge` operator is not the best solution for my use case, which is - "reset" the flow value and then suspend until the changes are propagating.

Here is a simplified example and an explanation:

```
val state1 = MutableStateFlow(1)
val state2 = MutableStateFlow(-99)
val merged = merge(state1, state2)

state1.value = 10
merged.first { it == 10 }
```

I was mistaken to think that the `merged` flow will emit 1 then -99 and then 10, and in the end my `first` call will succeed.

In reality `merged` is a "cold" flow, even though its sources are both "hot" flows. So it will not collect any data from its sources until we apply a terminal operator, which in our case is `first`.
When we call `first` it will collect both states, and since both are `MutableStateFlow`, they fire their current values right away, which means there is no guarantee which of the 2 values (10 or -99) we will get.

Answer (score 0):

Problem: Your flow wasn't directly linking the reset action to emitting the default value. That's why the reset didn't seem to work as expected.

Solution: Change the resetTrigger in ResettableFlow to simply signal a reset event, and then make sure that event triggers emitting the default value. in this case, the collect method is adjusted to listen for reset signals. Upon receiving a reset signal (Unit), it emits the defaultValue.

```html
class ResettableFlow<T>(private val source: Flow<T>, private val defaultValue: T) : Flow<T> {
    private val resetTrigger = MutableSharedFlow<Unit>() // This is your reset signal

    private val mergedFlow = flow {
        emit(defaultValue) // Start with the default value
        source.combine(resetTrigger) { sourceValue, _ ->
            sourceValue // Emit source value or default when reset is triggered
        }.collect { 
            emit(it) // Keep emitting values from source or reset
        }
    }

    override suspend fun collect(collector: FlowCollector<T>) {
        mergedFlow.collect {
            collector.emit(it) // Collect and handle the merged flow
        }
    }

    fun reset() {
        resetTrigger.tryEmit(Unit) // When reset, this triggers the flow to emit default value
    }
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, just copy your solution into the playground link I posted in the question.
And to be honest I don't see how the default value is emitted on reset in your solution, more detailed explanation would be nice.

Comment: I have a problem in previous code as it was not emitting the default value, now updated.. I tested this and it is working but you can confirm

Comment: What I'm trying to achieve might not be "correct" in context of async and reactive mindset of flows. First I ended up splitting reset into 2 operations if I want to suspend until default value propagates through all the flows downstream. Then I ended up restructuring my code to get rid of "waiting" for a proper value in flow, which doesn't fit into the reactive paradigm.
Your example will still fail for this case: val state = MutableStateFlow(1); val resettable = state.toResettable(0); state.value = 10; resettable.first { it == 10 }; println("found!")... so calling first() is the wrong part.

Comment: As I wrote, I'm not trying to find a solution anymore since my requirements were wrong. But I was trying to understand the technical part and how flows work. Now I know more about them then before.